# How to check external link validity in AEM 5.6?

Tags: aem

I want to check whether an external link is valid. I tried implementing it using the `getLink()` method of the [LinkChecker](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/rewriter/linkchecker/LinkChecker.html) interface. But I couldn't find any implementation class for the same. I did find a LinkCheckerImpl but it is deprecated since version 5.3. 
Does anyone have any idea how can I check validity of external links.

```
LinkCheckerSettings settings =  new LinkCheckerSettings();
String url = "http://www.boi.ie/personalLoan/calculator";
LinkCheckerImpl linkCheckerImpl = new LinkCheckerImpl();
Link link = linkCheckerImpl.getLink(url,settings);
```

Comment: Please link/elaborate the non-working solution you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ExternalLinkChecker](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/rewriter/linkchecker/ExternalLinkChecker.html) service to check for external links.

Sample JSP code for the same would be

```
ExternalLinkChecker checker = sling.getService(ExternalLinkChecker.class);
if (checker != null) {
    int status = checker.check("http://www.boi.ie/personalLoan/calculator");
    if (status == 200) {
        //Do Something
    } else {
        //Do Something Else
    }
}
```

If you are using the same in your bundle, use `@Reference` to get a reference to the `ExternalLinkChecker` class.

Comment: Can we do the same check in Javascript?